# Convert sql query to query builder using laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

1. Hi I my try to convert SQL query to Query Builder. My Sql query below like this

   ```
   SELECT exclusive_distributor_opens.distribution_code,exclusive_distributor_opens.distribution_name,exclusive_item_opens.item_code,exclusive_item_opens.item_name,SUM(exclusive_budget_items_details.dealer_contribution) as Total,exclusive_distributor_opens.date
   FROM exclusive_budget_masters
   JOIN exclusive_distributor_opens
     ON exclusive_budget_masters.distributor_id=exclusive_distributor_opens.id
   JOIN exclusive_budget_items_details
     ON exclusive_budget_masters.distributor_id=exclusive_budget_items_details.budget_master_id
   JOIN exclusive_item_opens
     ON exclusive_budget_items_details.item_id=exclusive_item_opens.id
   GROUP BY (exclusive_distributor_opens.distribution_code)
   HAVING exclusive_distributor_opens.date BETWEEN '2018-12-19' AND '2018-12-19'
   ORDER BY exclusive_distributor_opens.distribution_code DESC
   ```

2.My Query Builder Query like this

```
$results = DB::table('exclusive_budget_masters')
    ->join('exclusive_distributor_opens', 'exclusive_budget_masters.distributor_id', '=', 'exclusive_distributor_opens.id')
    ->join('exclusive_budget_items_details', 'exclusive_budget_masters.distributor_id' ,'=', 'exclusive_budget_items_details.budget_master_id')
    ->join('exclusive_item_opens', 'exclusive_budget_items_details.item_id', '=', 'exclusive_item_opens.id')
    ->select('exclusive_distributor_opens.distribution_code', 'exclusive_distributor_opens.distribution_name','exclusive_budget_items_details.customar_contribution', DB::raw('SUM(exclusive_budget_items_details.customar_contribution) As Total'))
    ->whereBetween('exclusive_distributor_opens.date', array('2018-12-19', '2018-12-19'))
    ->groupBy('exclusive_distributor_opens.distribution_code', 'exclusive_distributor_opens.distribution_name','exclusive_budget_items_details.customar_contribution')
    ->orderBy('exclusive_distributor_opens.date', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

My Query Output Result Comes like this:

[image]

But My Expected Result looks like this:

[image]

Please anybody help me.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect this to work?

Select part is missing or wrong:

- `exclusive_item_opens`.`item_code` **missing**
- `exclusive_item_opens`.`item_name` **missing**
- `exclusive_distributor_opens`.`date` **missing**

SUM Total column is wrong:
`SUM(exclusive_budget_items_details.dealer_contribution) as Total` vs
`DB::raw('SUM(exclusive_budget_items_details.customar_contribution) As Total')`

Your builder query looks like this:

```
SELECT `exclusive_distributor_opens`.`distribution_code`, 
           `exclusive_distributor_opens`.`distribution_name`, 
           `exclusive_budget_items_details`.`customar_contribution`, 
           Sum(exclusive_budget_items_details.customar_contribution) AS Total 
    FROM   `exclusive_budget_masters` 
           INNER JOIN `exclusive_distributor_opens` 
                   ON `exclusive_budget_masters`.`distributor_id` = 
                      `exclusive_distributor_opens`.`id` 
           INNER JOIN `exclusive_budget_items_details` 
                   ON `exclusive_budget_masters`.`distributor_id` = 
                      `exclusive_budget_items_details`.`budget_master_id` 
           INNER JOIN `exclusive_item_opens` 
                   ON `exclusive_budget_items_details`.`item_id` = 
                      `exclusive_item_opens`.`id` 
    WHERE  `exclusive_distributor_opens`.`date` BETWEEN ? AND ? 
    GROUP  BY `exclusive_distributor_opens`.`distribution_code`, 
              `exclusive_distributor_opens`.`distribution_name`, 
              `exclusive_budget_items_details`.`customar_contribution` 
    ORDER  BY `exclusive_distributor_opens`.`date` DESC
```

Comment: My selected part is ok. I want to group by only one column don't more column. I need this to present a report.

Comment: May be laravel new version  higher than  >7.4 not support group by multiple column, It support only One column....